# Not able to open Intellij

Tags: unix, intellij-idea

My unix instance is running on a shared server which is being used by a lot of people. We have a common location for softwares like eclipse and intellij.

However when I open intellij i get-

```
Startup Error: Unable to detect graphics environment
```

Can anyone explain how everyone else is able to open it but i can't?

Comment: Have you set your `DISPLAY`? Something like `$ export DISPLAY=:0.0`

Comment: No i haven't. i was not aware that we needed to do something like this. Can you give a little more detail?

Comment: [x(7) - Linux man page](https://linux.die.net/man/7/x)